# Count string length using external table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Suppose you have a table of data:

```
df<-tibble(person = c("Alice", "Bob", "Mary"),
           colour = c("Red", "Green", "Blue"),
           city = c("London", "Paris", "New York"))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  person colour city    
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   
1 Alice  Red    London  
2 Bob    Green  Paris   
3 Mary   Blue   New York
```

And a second table which contains the field names and the maximum string length of each field:

```
len<-tibble(field_name = c("person", "colour", "city"),
            field_length = c(12, 4, 6))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  field_name field_length
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 person               12
2 colour                4
3 city                  6
```

How can I check, for each field in `len`, whether a string in `df` is less than or equal to `len$field_length`, returning rows which fail the test?

**As an example:**

Output Row 1 in `df` would pass because:

- 'Alice' <= 12 characters long,
- 'Red' is <= 4 characters long and
- 'London' is <= 6 characters long.

However,

- **Row 2** would fail because:

  - 'Green' > 4 characters long and
- **Row 3** would fail because:

  - 'New York' > 6 characters long.

Thus the returned data frame should only display `Rows 2` and `Row 3` of the original `df`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution with `c_across()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(any(nchar(c_across(everything())) > len$field_length)) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   person colour city    
#   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   
# 1 Bob    Green  Paris   
# 2 Mary   Blue   New York
```

Comment: This looks like a really neat solution. I've not come across `c_across` before.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it avoids a `left_join`.

Answer (score 2):

Using base R with `mapply` :

```
df[rowSums(mapply(function(x, y) nchar(x) > y, df, len$field_length)) > 0, ]

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  person colour city    
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   
#1 Bob    Green  Paris   
#2 Mary   Blue   New York
```

If column names in `df` are not in the same order as `len$field_name` use `df[len$field_name]` in `mapply`.

---

In `tidyverse` we can get data in long format join it with `len` data by column name, select the rows which fail and get data in wide format again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  left_join(len, by = c('name' = 'field_name')) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  filter(any(nchar(value) > field_length)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-field_length) %>%
  pivot_wider()
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak for saving me again! I was surprisingly close with my own `tidyverse` solution (unpublished) by going down the `pivot_` route, but didn't manage to get a full solution before posting here.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to solve your problem in terms of 2 matrices, first the length of each of your entries:

```
nchar(as.matrix(df))
     person colour city
[1,]      5      3    6
[2,]      3      5    5
[3,]      4      4    8
```

And a corresponding matrix of allowed length:

```
allowed = replicate(nrow(df),len$field_length[match(colnames(df),len$field_name)])

allowed

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   12   12   12
[2,]    4    4    4
[3,]    6    6    6
```

Then matrix wise comparison, and only keep those where the rowSums() are

```
df[rowMeans(nchar(as.matrix(df)) > allowed)>0,]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  person colour city    
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   
1 Bob    Green  Paris   
2 Mary   Blue   New York
```

If your two data.frames are already in the same order like your example, you can do (thanks to @zx8754) for pointing it out:

```
df[rowMeans(nchar(as.matrix(df)) > len$field_length)>0,]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  person colour city    
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   
1 Bob    Green  Paris   
2 Mary   Blue   New York
```

Comment: I hadn't considered this approach, thank you for posting. I will keep this in the back of my mind for future problems.

Comment: Interesting approach, slight improvement, no need for *allowed*, try: `nchar(as.matrix(df)) > len$field_length`

Comment: True, if it is already in the same order. I can add that. Good tip. Lol I am very uneasy about replicating vectors sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Pivot `df` into the same format as `len` and join the two. After this, it is trivial to compare each string to the `field_length`.

```
library(tidyverse)

test_result_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = 'field_name') %>% 
  left_join(len, by = 'field_name') %>% 
  mutate(test_passed = str_length(value) <= field_length) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(all_passed = all(test_passed))

df[!test_result_df$all_passed,]
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  person colour city    
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   
1 Bob    Green  Paris   
2 Mary   Blue   New York
```